# Search for a specific pattern in a string C#

Tags: c#, regex

I got a string which can has a part which looks like this: "1.0.0" but it can also look like this "1.0.0.0" and these are the parts I need out of the string.
I tried using this regular expression:

```
var dotPart = Regex.Match(infoString, @"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.d+)*");
```

This works fine on "1.0.0" but not on "1.0.0.0" which then returns only the first 3 digits instead of the last.
How do I fix my pattern? And for general knowledge, what is wrong with the pattern I wrote?

Comment: You haven't shown how you're extracting the values from the match. It would really help if you could show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the last backslash in `\d`:

```
var dotPart = Regex.Match(infoString, @"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.\d+)*");
```

Comment: god dammit! How did this thing actually slow me down

Comment: ...it happens to all of us once in a while :-)

Answer (score 0):

This tool always helped me.
[RegEx builder](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)